# Combining some service code with mysql

Tags: android, android-service

My goal is to connect to a remote mySQL DB through PHP make a request, find out if there are new messages available and if the answer is yes, then send a notification to the device to display it. There should be a working example of something like this, since it's the base of any serious app that deals with updates and/or messaging.
So my PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

 if(!$con)
 die('could not connect: ' .mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db("mydatabasename",$con);

 $result = mysql_query("select count(*) from (select * from notificari n, notificari_destinatii d where n.dest_notif_id=d.id_master) as tbl 
where id_user=247 and date(data_notif)=date(now())");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $output[]=$row;
 }

 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

So this php tells me the number of notifications the user 247 received today. I want to get this number in my service, and compare it to a local (SQLite DB table) number of notifications. And if the remote number is greater than the local number, I want to display a notification on the device saying: "You have a new message waiting" and then increment the local number so the next time the service asks PHP, the remote number and the local number will be equal, so no notification will be fired.

This operation must be done every 10 minutes.
Can this be done in a service? (async call to php, SQLite select statement, notification creation)?

How can I achieve this? At first I thought of a service and went [**here**](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html) This is how I can make the service cycle, so every xx minutes I can fire an action. But where do I implement the PHP call inside this service tutorial?

And how can I change the code to add the functionality to automatically start the service from above on Android BOOT (code is [**here**](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/start-activity-or-service-on-boot.html)), so the user can not have the excuse that he did not receive the message because he did not start the app today.

So how can I combine the two tutorials into one?

Then I stumbled upon [**this example**](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) with syncAdapters, and now I am confused, because I do not understand how can I apply this to my case? And what is the best approach? The service one or the syncAdapter one?
Also I have problems understanding the concept in the code for syncAdapter as it would apply for my needs described above

Please try and help me with my problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial for starting on boot, you just need to start your service from the BroadcastReceiver.  And the service can either be your own code that you make up, or you can use the sync adapter framework.  Sounds like sync adapter would be good for your needs, though I've never used it.

Comment: That is my problem too. I never used the syncAdapter nor do I understand how it can help me for my specific need. I managed to put together a service application that does what I want (sends an Async Call to PHP every xxx minutes and retrieves the number that I want) however I am not sure I should pursue this method. That is why I was asking the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Until now I managed to write a service app (I think that is how it is called). And the app uses the AlarmManager to schedule the calls to the php web-service. Also I implemented the AsyncTask that does the calling. So now, my app/service works. I am still not convinced that it is a good approach and I have not received any pieces of code or ideas on how to adapt the syncAdapter to my needs. So I will probably go with my way, unless I get a more complete answer to my problem.